# How to get URNs or ID for Organizations that a user is associated with in Linkedin latest api?

Tags: python-3.x, linkedin-api

I used below code to get the user details.But in that response,I did not get the Organization(Page) details associated with the user.

```
import requests

# Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with your actual LinkedIn access token
access_token = 'token'

# LinkedIn API endpoint
api_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo'

# Set the Authorization header with the access token
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

# Make the GET request
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Request was successful
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
else:
    # Request failed
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

I could not find anything in the documentation to get the organization details.Can anyone provide a latest endpoint to get the organization details associated with the user.